# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Caleb]
[image: Susan]
[image: Soldarnal]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why when the site graduates there will be community elections.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Are we still having elections in a few weeks? ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii The hours turn into days, the days into weeks, the weeks into years.

Comment: @Caleb I thought the days turned into "[six to eight weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog/190745#190745)". ;)

Answer (score 7):

It's been a privilege serving this community, but my current life circumstances no longer allow me to spend as much time and energy moderating this site as I'd like. As such, I'm stepping down as a moderator pro tempore. I'll still be around moderating the site as a community member (remember: this site is moderated by YOU, e.g. every member of the community), and I look forward to continuing to read interesting questions and answers (and posting some from time to time as I'm able). Thank you.

Comment: It's been a privilege to work with you. -99 for ditching the mod crew, +100 to know you won't be a stranger.

Comment: It's been a privilege learning from you. Your tutelage that really helped me "get" the SO/SE model. [Thanks, Dan!](https://media.giphy.com/media/n5oYbKrHYXylq/giphy.gif)

Comment: Thank you for taking on the job. I've been pleased with your tenure in every way. Well done!