# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Biblical Hermeneutics’s [first moderator election](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: Jon Ericson] [image: curiousdannii] [image: Steve Taylor]

They’ll be taking over as [the new crew here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! Thank you so much to the departing Beta moderators, Susan and Soldarnal for your time here! This site wouldn't be where it is without your guidance.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6610233599197184/0).

Comment: Congratulations to those elected - well done.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to thank everyone who voted! And I'd like to thank Susan and Soldarnal for their service as [Moderators *pro tempore*](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/moderator-pro-tem-announcement). We've been so fortunate to have [a long list of volunteer moderators](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/148/revisions) (in no particular order):

- Susan
- Soldarnal
- Caleb
- Jack
- Richard
- Dan
- Ray

These folks have done the lion's share of moderating over the years and we stand on the shoulder's of giants. I'm excited curiousdannii and Steve have been added to that list. (And thank you, Tony, for nominating. It was [a *very close* result](https://www.opavote.com/results/6610233599197184/0) in the end.) This site simply wouldn't function without the dedication of moderators who handle flags and set the tone of the site.

Comment: Thanks for your continuing work and effort - great job.  Congratulations.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you all for volunteering to take up this role! This site continues to grow and I'm glad for it to have your efforts in helping cultivate it. I'm confident you will all handle the responsibilities well. Congratulations!

And also congratulations to the BH.SE community on reaching this milestone. It's perhaps been a slow build, but the race is not always to the swift as the saying goes, and we continue to create a wealth of helpful questions and answers for folks out there looking for them.

Comment: Thank you for your service over the years!

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts - great job!

Answer (score 4):

Thank you everyone for voting. I'll endeavour to serve you all, hopefully you won't even notice what I and the other mods do. If you do have any concerns with our moderation acts, you can always write here in Meta, and we'll treat what you say very seriously.

Comment: Congratulations - you will do a very good job.  Thanks for volunteering.